# Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation when calculating a value for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query is like this. I am trying to calculate the totalperPax column then insert it in the table but it gives me warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

```
INSERT INTO columnTotal
( 
 ID, 
 Column1,
 Column2,
 Sold,
 Total,
 TotalPerPax
)
  SELECT 
    D.ID,
    'A' AS Column1,
    'A' AS Column2,
    SUM(COALESCE(D.Sold, 0)) As Sold,
    SUM(COALESCE(D.Total,0)) As Total, 
    NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN D.Code1 IS NOT NULL 
        THEN D.Total ELSE 0 END), 0) /
    NULLIF(SUM(D.Sold), 0) AS TotalPerPax
    FROM Data D
    INNER JOIN Map M
    ON M.Code1 = D.Code1
    OR M.Code2 = D.Code2
    GROUP BY D.ID
```

Sample DDL and DML are in here [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2028a529dde4c8f5e25d0c72cb949a3d). Can anyone can help me to fix my query? Thanks

Comment: Are the results you get not what you are expecting?  That warning is just that, not an error, and can frequently be safely ignored.

Comment: Hi. @squillman Thank you for your response. I want to know if there is a way to improve my current query. Much better if the warning will be completely gone :)

Comment: It's not necessarily a problem in your query, it's just telling you that there are NULL values in your data that are not being used.

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: You could remove it with `NULLIF(SUM(ISNULL(D.Sold, 0)), 0)` Side point: `ISNULL` is faster than `COALESCE` on SQL Server

Comment: A little more context that can help decide between COALESCE and ISNULL other than a generic claim of faster: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/ :-)

Answer (score 0):

when D.Total is null you'll get warning

```
NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN D.Code1 IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL(D.Total, 0) ELSE 0 END), 0) / NULLIF(SUM(D.Sold), 0) AS TotalPerPax
```

the same for SUM(D.Sold)

```
SUM(ISNULL(D.Sold, 0))
```